# Saving zend sub_form into session variable

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, session

Hello i've ran into a problem with zend framework. I want to make a multi-step form with zend but this isn't supported by zend, so can i save sub_form in session variables and validate them one by one and then at the end of the main form take all of sub_form to display all the form ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Here is my forms code :

```
   public function init()
{
    /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */
    $this->setAttrib("class", "form-horizontal well");

    $name = $this->createElement('text', 'name', array(
                                                        "label" => $this->getTranslator()->translate('ADD_NAME'), 
                                                        "description" => $this->getTranslator()->translate('ADD_EXAMPLE_NAME')
                                                        ))->setRequired(true);

    $trigram = $this->createElement('text', 'trigram', array(
                                                                "label" => $this->getTranslator()->translate('ADD_TRIGRAM'),
                                                                "description" => $this->getTranslator()->translate('ADD_EXAMPLE_TRIGRAM')
                                                                ))->setRequired(true);
    $environment = $this->createElement('select', 'environment', array(
                                                                        "label" => $this->getTranslator()->translate('ADD_ENVIRONMENT')
                                                                        ))->setRequired(true);
    $url_clientsite = $this->createElement('text', 'url_clientsite', array(
                                                                            "label" => $this->getTranslator()->translate('ADD_URL_CLIENT'),
                                                                            "description" => $this->getTranslator()->translate('ADD_EXAMPLE_URL')
                                                                            ))->setRequired(true);

    $check_box = $this->createElement('multicheckbox', 'components', array(
                                                                            "multiOptions" => array(
                                                                                                    "mon" => " BDD Mona",
                                                                                                    "sta" => " BDD Stats",
                                                                                                    "log" => " BDD Logs",
                                                                                                    "sal" => " Sali",
                                                                                                    "agg" => " StatsAggregator",
                                                                                                    "etl" => " ETL",
                                                                                                    "jvs" => " JavaScript",
                                                                                                    "adm" => " Admin"
                                                                                                    )))->setRequired(true);

    $step_1 = new Zend_Form_SubForm();  
    $step_1->addElements(array(
                                $name,
                                $trigram,
                                $environment,
                                $url_clientsite,
                                ));

    $this->addSubForm($step_1, 'step1');

    $step_2 = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
    $step_2->addElement($check_box);
    $this->addSubForm($step_2, 'step2');    

    $step_3 = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
    $step_3->addElements();

    $this->addSubForm($step_3, 'step3');

}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. But what problem? Maybe you have some code?

Comment: No, precisely, i'm doing the conception but i can give you my forms declaration.